# Push to deploy on bare repository - Git

Tags: git

i've got a git repository (development directory) and a remote bare git repository (production server)

When i :

```
git push origin production
```

The commits are updated on the production server but the files are not copied to the directory.

How can i do that ?

How can i automatise that ?

Thanks!

Comment: "files are not copied" in the sense new files? If new files are not added to the index git will not recognize. Use "$ git add ." or "$ git add <filename.ext>" , then commit the files added and push the commits the origin

Comment: files are staged, then i want to push and deploy my last commit to the production server, But after my push production origin i cant see commits but real files are NOT updated.. I want to find a way to deploy directly with one command

Comment: Check for the .gitignore

Comment: You probably want to look at using a hook like post-receive, so committing triggers a script that does whatever deploy work you want done.

Comment: Bare repository doesn't have working directory by definition. If you got files copied eksewhere that was a custom setup probably via hooks as Dan points out.